# SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Ive read documentation from several pages on SO of this issue, but i havent been able to fix my issue with this particular error.

```
    throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')
    ^

Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string
    at Object.continueSession (C:\Users\CNFis\Desktop\WulfDevelopments\ThePantry\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:24:11)
    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (C:\Users\CNFis\Desktop\WulfDevelopments\ThePantry\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:257:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at C:\Users\CNFis\Desktop\WulfDevelopments\ThePantry\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\CNFis\Desktop\WulfDevelopments\ThePantry\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CNFis\Desktop\WulfDevelopments\ThePantry\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
```

its as if in my `connectDB()` function its not recognizing the password to the database. I am trying to run a `seeder.js` script to seed the database with useful information for testing purposes, and if i run `npm run server` which is a script that just starts a nodemon server, itll connect to the DB just fine. but when i try to run my script to seed data, i am returning this error.

```js
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import colors from "colors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const user = "postgres";
const host = "localhost";
const database = "thePantry";
const port = "5432";

const connectDB = async () => {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, process.env.DBPASS, {
    host,
    port,
    dialect: "postgres",
    logging: false,
  });
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.".bgGreen.black);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:".bgRed.black, error);
  }
};

export default connectDB;
```

above is my connectDB() file, and again, it works when i run the server normally. but i receive this error only when trying to seed the database. Ill post my seeder script below:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import colors from "colors";
import users from "./data/users.js";

import User from "./models/userModel.js";

import connectDB from "./config/db.js";

dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env.DBPASS);

connectDB();

const importData = async () => {
  try {
    await User.drop();
    await User.sync();

    await User.bulkCreate(users);

    console.log("Data Imported".green.inverse);
    process.exit();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`${e}`.red.inverse);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

const destroyData = async () => {
  try {
    await User.bulkDestroy();

    console.log("Data Destroyed".red.inverse);
    process.exit();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`${e}`.red.inverse);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

if (process.argv[2] === "-d") {
  destroyData();
} else {
  importData();
}
```

Comment: I got this error when my local development database was off (because I restarted my computer) 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, i may have figured this out by playing around in another project with sequelize, as it turns out, the initial connection to the database in my `server.js` file, honestly means nothing. Unlike `Mongoose` where the connection is available across the whole app. its not the same for `Sequelize` this connection that it creates is only apparent in certain places, for example i was trying the same process in my other project as i am here, except i was trying to read data from my DB using the `model` that i built with `sequelize` and i was receiving the same type error, i went into where i defined the model and made a `sequelize` connection there, and i was then able to read from the database using that object model.

Long story short, to fix the error in this app i have to place a connection to the database in the `seeder.js` file or i have to place a connection in the `User` model (this is ideal since ill be using the model in various places) to be able to seed information or read information from the database.

Answer (score 15):

Add your .env file in your project, I think your .env file is missing in your project folder.
add like this:
[image]

Comment: This was not it, as i stated in my post back in November, the Connection wasnt available in other areas of the App,

Comment: Ok, but this answer is helpful to others if they have a same issue.

Comment: its not though, the .env wasnt missing from the folder structure. this answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: I think this solves the problem in some cases, maybe not in your case...

Answer (score 5):

Here is my case. I have postgresql connection url in my enviroment like:

```
POSTGRES=postgres://postgres:test@localhost:5432/default
```

But my config getting like:

```
POSTGRES_DB_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_DB_PORT=5432
...rest of configs
```

Now it has resolved.

Comment: I was looking for solution then saw myself. It is good answer i can say. Because i was using strapi. Then check the environment i saw that there is no password. Now it works. Thanks to me ^.^

Comment: The same happened to me

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and another solution different from the accepted solution here solved my issue, so I wanted to explain that to this lovely community, too.

Firstly, when I faced the issue, ran my project in debug mode and reached the code below.

```
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
```

The problem here is actually obvious when I saw first, there is a problem in .env file as mentioned in the solutions above. In my process.env is defined as like as following line: `DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@IP_adress:port/db_name` and my config.js file is in the following format:

```
module.exports = {
  "development": {
    "url":"postgres://username:password@IP_adress:port/db_name",
    "dialect": "postgres",    
  }, ...
}
```

So as a solution, I come with the following fix for the parameters that are inside Sequelize(...). My solution below is totally worked for me and I hope it also works for you too.

```
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.url, config);
}
```

Finally, the point you need to be careful about what you have written to the config file. That's the most important in this case.

Farewell y'all.

Answer (score 1):

My problem in this case was that I was using `dotenv` and I refactored the `process.env` *outside* of the function being *called* to the root of the module

This **worked** because `dotenv` has been initialised in the module *calling* `connectDB`:

```js
// module database.js

const connectDB = () => {
  const { POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD } = process.env
  ...
}
```

This **fails** because `dotenv` has not been initialised inside the module:

```js
// module database.js
const { POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD } = process.env

const connectDB = () => {
  ...
}
```

This **works** again because `dotenv` is being initialised in the module.

```js
// module database.js
import 'dotenv/config' // populate process.env for imported files

const { POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD } = process.env

const connectDB = () => {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

today i have same problem like this, so if you use database with type relational. you must define password from database.

```js
const user = "postgres";
    const host = "localhost";
    const database = "thePantry";
    const password = "yourdatabasepassword"; if null > const password = ""; 
    const port = "5432";
```

but, if you use database with type non-relational, as long as the attributes are the same, you can immediately run the program as you defined it

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue because I was trying to execute `nodemon` from a parent folder. Once I changed my pwd, the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For your seeder script, i'm doing something similar but not using Sequilize, just the `node-postgres` package in an ExpressJS app.

To give context (so you know if this applies to your situation)

I run a separate script for testing, which uses database credentials to test batched emailing. So, I need to access my database (eventually will migrate it to an AWS lambda function).

I need to access my database and run sequential actions, since I'm not spinning up my server, all that 'under the hood' processes that would normally start your connection pool is probably not running. My guess ( I know it's an old post but this may help others).

Try passing your hardcoded password credentials. first on your seeder.js file. (i'm sure you've tried this already).

Try creating a new Pool within your seeder script and pass it your credentials (try hard coding it first to see if it works).

Pool in postgres takes a client config with the following properties (i  use this to get mine to work).

```
const pool = new Pool({
  user: '****',
  database: '****',
  password: '****',
  port: 5432,
  host: '****',
  max: 5,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 5000,
})
```

I imagine sequilize will have a similar configuration, so try playing around with that.

Then I just connect to the pool and do everything I'd normally do.

Hope this helps with a bit of the troubleshooting. I had the EXACT same error message earlier. Ultimately I had to restructure my code to 'boot up' the Client/Connection Pool for the database. It sounds like you're not properly 'booting up' your connection so try doing it manually within your seeder script (don't pass process.env.DB_PASSWORD  at first).

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when running a `npx sequelize-cli db:...` command

and my postgres server wasn't running or able to accept connections.

To fix it, I had to be running: `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that my 'fix' matches the problem entirely, and is pretty simplistic, but I did the following:

1. sudo -u postgres psql  (this will display the postgres users)
2. In postgres:  ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'password_here';

In db.js:

```
const { Client } = require("pg");let db = new Client({
    connectionString: "postgresql://postgres:password_here@localhost/dbName"  
});db.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with drizzle ORM in a turborepo set up. The solution:

```
// This failed
// const connection = await mysql.createConnection(process.env.DB_APEX_K8S!)

// This worked:
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_K8S_APEX_host!,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_K8S_APEX_port!),
  user: process.env.DB_K8S_APEX_user!,
  password: process.env.DB_K8S_APEX_password!,
  database: process.env.DB_K8S_APEX_database!,
})
export const db_apex_k8s = drizzle(connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your database password has any escape characters (eg. @, %, etc.). If that's the case, replace the special characters with the escape character value. (eg. @ -> %40). This worked for me so it could be one possible cause

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issues a while ago whilst connecting a Nest js application to a supabase instance from a monorepo setup.

And the issues was that i had configService to load the environment variables into my backend application , but it would only work if the .env file is at the root folder of the workspace/application in your case.

So.. I simply moved the `.env` file to the workspace folder, and i could access the values from there.

In summary, it gives that error because it doesnt find a value for the environment key that was being passed. if you wanna test this, try to print out the environment variable in any of your services.

Lmk if it helps.